# Grand canonical ensemble in describing inhomogeneous fluids

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density-functional-theory

I have seen that in the theories of inhomogeneous fluids  classical Density Functional Theory is used, but the treatment is preferably done in Grand Canonical Ensemble. What is the reason for choosing Grand Canonical Ensemble ?

Answer (score 0):

In the [thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit) it does not matter in which statistic ensemble you work. The grand canonical ensemble is chosen in this case in order to make the calculations more easy (you could in principle use the canonical ensemble or the micro-canonical ensemble)

Comment: Can you give an example where it simplifies the calculations than in micro-canonical or canonical ensemble ?